# Can't figure out split() function

Tags: python, list, split

hope you are doing great!

I got stuck with split() function. I have looked up in search, that split() returns a list.

Example:

```
text = "158.0-165.4"
splittext = text.split("-")
```

Is it the correct way to get values 158.0 and 165.4?
Since the splittext is now a list, how do I get second value for example?

```
var1 , var2 = splittext.split("-")
```

What i get is just "-"

I understand that these are simple things and I should figure them out checking the documentation, but I don't get what I am doing wrong :c

Please help, appreciate it!

Comment: `splittext` is an array of 2 values, `var1, var2 = splittext` will unpack. `var2` will now have the second value. Alternatively, you can just index `splittext`, e.g. `var2 = splittext[1]`

Comment: Are you sure? I got something different.

Comment: You couldn't printed `splittext.split("-")` to see what it was

Answer (score 0):

```
var1, var2 = text.split("-")
```

will do what you're looking for.  Since the split method returns an array, you can't use the `str.split` method on that (i.e. you can't do `splittext.split("-")`)

You could, of course, also access the values using indices:

```
splittext = text.split("-")
var1 = splittext[0]
var2 = splittext[1]
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response! Works like a charm and makes me feel really dumb, haha. =D

Answer (score 0):

You are doing one step too far.

```
text = "158.0-165.4"
splittext = text.split("-")
```

This makes **splittext** an array. splittext[0] = 158.0, splittext[1] is 165.4.

What you want to do is:

```
text = "158.0-165.4"
var1, var2 = text.split("-")
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is well-built for experimentation. Running your example in the shell, I get

```
>>> text = "158.0-165.4"
>>> splittext = text.split("-")
>>> splittext
['158.0', '165.4']
>>> var1 , var2 = splittext.split("-")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
>>>
```

oops! That's different than you claim. Trying it another way

```
>>> text = "158.0-165.4"
>>> var1, var2 = text.split("-")
>>> var1
'158.0'
>>> var2
'165.4'
```

That looks right.